# Show the contents of xml file in wpf window

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

My xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<Dictionary>
    <dictName>Мой словарь</dictName>    
    <Word id="1">
        <wordName>Hello</wordName>
        <Translation>Привет</Translation>
    </Word>
        <Word id="2">
        <wordName>Tree</wordName>
        <Translation>Дерево</Translation>
    </Word>         
</Dictionary>
```

How can I display the contents in a table with headings "ID" "Word" "Translation"?

Comment: This should help: http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XmlDataProvider. You can use XmlDataProvider to read XML data. Try this [link](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.com/2011/11/binding-wpf-datagrid-with-xml-file.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<Dictionary>
    <dictName>Мой словарь</dictName>    
    <Word id="1">
        <wordName>Hello</wordName>
        <Translation>Привет</Translation>
    </Word>
    <Word id="2">
        <wordName>Tree</wordName>
        <Translation>Дерево</Translation>
    </Word>         
</Dictionary>

XML File

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.DataGridAndXMLData"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataGrid With XmlData" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="DictionaryData" Source="Dictionary.xml" XPath="Dictionary/Word" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="CustomerGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DictionaryData},XPath=*}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@wordName}"
                                    Header="ID" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Translation}"
                                    Header="Translation" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: XMLDataProvider was exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, поменяй структуру и внеси ID внутрь World'a тогда используя обычных XML десериализатор получишь List классов World

```
class World
{
    int ID {get;set;}
    int Word {get;set;}
    int Transltion {get;set;}
}
```

А потом просто биндишь DataGrid к листу.

First of all change the structure, id should be inside the World, the use simple XML deserializer to get List of worlds

```
class World
{
    int ID {get;set;}
    int Word {get;set;}
    int Transltion {get;set;}
}
```

And then just bing DataGrid to the List

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinqToXml to query the information and return a list. 
You can then bind it to a datagrid.

Maybe some grids also support XDocument as DataSource also...